# Converting RichTextBox content to Word without losing formatting, in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, richtextbox

I copied word content to richtextbox without loosing format perfectly, but now I am editing the content in the richtextbox. Now I want to copy the richtextbox content to a word document without losing any formating, in vb.net. How do you do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can copy the RTF content to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

When you paste it to Word, the format will be preserved

Comment: Good idea but it's not the best solution. How can you export from the App without losing formatting. OR how can I paste the contents using C#

Answer (score 0):

If you use the richtextbox's savetofile method, you can save the content to an rtf file that the user (or your app) can open in Word.